# How to write a closure in livescript?

Tags: closures, livescript

How to write a closure in livescript

```
for i from 1 to 10
  cb = -> console.log i
  set-timeout cb, i*1000
```

to get 1 to 10 instead of ten times 10 ?

Answer (score 5):

```
for let i from 1 to 10
  cb = -> console.log i
  set-timeout cb, i*1000
```